# Deleting xinetd caused plesk removal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, plesk

I installed a VNC-server and read somewhere I had to install xinetd. A little later I decided to remove the VNC-server so I also removed xinetd. It seems that xinetd removes some plesk-related-files, if not the whole plesk-package.

Now mails aren't coming in and of course plesk is not working. Any ideas to fix this?

Maybe some important logs:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 libdevel-symdump-perl psa-awstats-configurator libtokyocabinet8 xsltproc bind9 sharutils log4cpp-plesk libdigest-sha1-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-dns-perl psa-pear libfile-copy-recursive-perl php5-xsl postfix re2c bind9utils libnet-xwhois-perl update-inetd unzip pp-sitebuilder-default-templates awstats postfix-pcre php5-sqlite libsqlite0 tk php5-gd gcc-4.4 libapache2-reload-perl psa-spf2 psa-php5-configurator spamc psa-courier-imap php5-curl libt1-5 psa-mail-driver-common gcc xfonts-base psa-ftputil libbsd-resource-perl libapache2-mod-python libmyodbc libvncserver0 php5-ioncube-loader psa-locale-base-en-us liberror-perl libapache2-mod-perl2 webalizer tcl libgd2-xpm tcl8.4 php5-imap libsocket6-perl zip libc6-dev tk8.4 libdb4.7 bsd-mailx psa-logrotate libsasl2-modules-sqlite3 php5-mysql libnetaddr-ip-perl linux-libc-dev manpages-dev libmail-spf-perl php5-cli sqlite3 libc-dev-bin pp-sitebuilder-skins binutils sw-libmilter sw-libsqlite3-0 libsys-hostname-long-perl libdigest-hmac-perl python-libxml2 spamassassin sw-doctrine libio-socket-inet6-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  plesk-core plesk-l10n plesk-mail-pc-driver pp-sitebuilder psa psa-backup-manager psa-horde psa-imp psa-ingo psa-kronolith psa-libxml-proxy psa-mimp psa-mnemo psa-passwd psa-proftpd
  psa-spamassassin psa-turba psa-updates psa-vhost xinetd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
After this operation, 464MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 69919 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing psa-mnemo ...
Removing psa-turba ...
Removing psa-passwd ...
Removing psa-ingo ...
Removing psa-mimp ...
Removing psa-kronolith ...
Removing psa-imp ...
No valid mailman bindir detected
Removing psa-horde ...
Removing psa-updates ...
Removing psa ...
Removing plesk-l10n ...
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/common/resources/languages/ja-JP/components/forms' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/common/resources/languages/ja-JP/components' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/common/resources/languages/ja-JP' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/smb/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/web' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/smb/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/redirect' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/smb/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/email-address' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/smb/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/smb/application/resources/languages/ja-JP' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/domain' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/server' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers/update' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/controllers' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/components/forms/service-plan' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/components/forms' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP/components' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing plesk-l10n, directory '/opt/psa/admin/panel/application/resources/languages/ja-JP' not empty so not removed.
Removing psa-spamassassin ...
Delete spamassassin preferences from .qmail files for mailnames
Removing `diversion of /etc/init.d/spamassassin to /usr/share/spamassassin/spamassassin.init.real by psa-spamassassin'
Removing psa-backup-manager ...
Removing psa-libxml-proxy ...
Removing plesk-core ...
Stopping psa...                                                       done
Removing plesk-mail-pc-driver ...
Removing psa-proftpd ...
Removing xinetd ...
 * Stopping internet superserver xinetd
   ...done.
Note: all inetd services have been terminated.
 * Stopping internet superserver xinetd
   ...done.
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

Should a Plesk-reinstall do the trick? Will I lose data?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to reinstall your system. Simply reinstall the package except for xinetd.

`sudo apt-get install plesk-core plesk-l10n plesk-mail-pc-driver pp-sitebuilder psa psa-backup-manager psa-horde psa-imp psa-ingo psa-kronolith psa-libxml-proxy psa-mimp psa-mnemo psa-passwd psa-proftpd psa-spamassassin psa-turba psa-updates psa-vhost`

That will do he trick.